# upload big file to nginx failed

Tags: nginx

I set a nginx server and trying to upload a file which is 500M. But the uploading will be interrupted when the progress reach to about 50% - 60%. So I guess there should be some directive to set this. I tried set client_max_body_size to 600M, it does not work.

==
Sorry, guys, I overlooked my file size, it exceeds 600M. Now I change the value to 1g, it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the `client_max_body_size` is the key.